# Telnet connection using .net

Tags: c#, sockets, telnet

Our office currently uses telnet to query an external server. The procedure is something like this.

1. Connect - telnet opent 128........ 25000
2. Query - we paste the query and then hit alt + 019
3. Response - We receive the response as text in the telnet window

So I’m trying to make this queries automatic using a c# app. My code is the following

First the connection. (No exceptions)

```
    SocketClient = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    String szIPSelected = txtIPAddress.Text;
    String szPort = txtPort.Text;
    int alPort = System.Convert.ToInt16(szPort, 10);

    System.Net.IPAddress remoteIPAddress = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(szIPSelected);
    System.Net.IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint = new System.Net.IPEndPoint(remoteIPAddress, alPort);
    SocketClient.Connect(remoteEndPoint);
```

Then I send the query (No exceptions)

```
    string data ="some query";
    byte[] byData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
    SocketClient.Send(byData);
```

Then I try to receive the response

```
    byte[] buffer = new byte[10];
    Receive(SocketClient, buffer, 0, buffer.Length, 10000);
    string str = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    txtDataRx.Text = str;

public static void Receive(Socket socket, byte[] buffer, int offset, int size, int timeout)
{
  int startTickCount = Environment.TickCount;
  int received = 0;  // how many bytes is already received
  do
  {
    if (Environment.TickCount > startTickCount + timeout)
      throw new Exception("Timeout.");
    try
    {
      received += socket.Receive(buffer, offset + received, size - received, SocketFlags.None);
    }
    catch (SocketException ex)
    {
      if (ex.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.WouldBlock ||
          ex.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.IOPending ||
          ex.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.NoBufferSpaceAvailable)
      {
        // socket buffer is probably empty, wait and try again
        Thread.Sleep(30);
      }
      else
        throw ex;  // any serious error occurr
    }
  } while (received < size);
}
```

Every time I try to receive the response I get "an exsiting connetion has forcibly closed by the remote host" if open telnet and send the same query I get a response right away

Any ideas, or suggestions?

Comment: Are you sending the Alt+019 in your automated query? Not related to your question, but you should just use 'throw' and not 'throw ex' to rethrow the exception. 'throw' will keep the stacktrace intact, not that this is your issue here, just some usefull info.

Comment: I dont know how to send the Alt + 019 if you hit it in notepad it doesnt print anything it just work in telnet, I've been trying to find some reference fot the Alt + 019 in google but no luck.

Comment: @alejandrobog, add the byte 19 as the last byte in your buffer. Ascii 19 is a control character so it might have significance to the endpoint server.

Comment: Thanks that sound right, i will try in a few minutes. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @Chris Taylor, I add the byte 19 and it workded! Please post it as an answer so I can give you credit. Thanks

Comment: @alejandrobog, that is great. I am glad you could resolve the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the comment exchange between you and I, it would seem that you need to append Ascii code 19 (0x13) to the end of your query.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, problems of this sort are easily resolved by using a network analysis tool (sniffer) such as [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/s).

More specifically, the telnet protocol includes a negotiation step at the the start of the session.  I'm guessing that if you ignore this, the host is unhappy.  Using Wireshark on the successful telnet connection will show you what you're missing.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of a telnet library along with a program that uses it to log into a Cisco router and download the IOS configuration.

http://www.xpresslearn.com/networking/code/csharp-telnet-client