# Test telnet communication on remote computer using VB.net?

Tags: vb.net

I have a central server and I need to write a bit of vb.net which will see if I can telnet to a specified server on a specified port.

Is there anyway this can be done in VB.net?  I thought about sending command prompts to the remote server to execute telnet, then output the logs of netsh and read those and send the information back to the central server for review.

Its a very messy way of doing it, so I was just wondering if there was an easier way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just create a TcpClient object with the IP address of the target server and port (typically 23 for telnet).  Then call Connect!

See here for more info:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx

Something like this (may not be exact):

```
Try

   Dim telnetServerIp As String = "192.168.100.55"
   Dim telnetPort As Integer = 23
   Dim client As New TcpClient(telnetServerIp, telnetPort)
   MessageBox.Show("Server is reachable")
Catch ex As Exception 
   MessageBox.Show("Could not reach server")
End Try
```

Be advised this is sample code.  You'd want to clean up (close/dispose) the connection (TcpClient) object when you were done, etc.  But it should get you started.

Comment: I'm still at a loss here :(  Trying to get my head around thing

Comment: @GregHesp I'll revise to add detail, but just to confirm...all you want to know is if a certain server is reachable by Telnet right?

Comment: Thanks.  My requirement is to be able to find out if Server1 can communicate with ServerX on PortX.  I used to do this manually by logging onto Server1 and typing "telnet ServerX PortX"

Comment: You are still going to have to run this on Server1.  It is the only way to know for sure.

Comment: Thanks.  If thats the I can copy the file to the server, run it, copy the results back and read the results file

Answer (score 0):

You should try something to implement this. there are lots help available for `Telnet communication` using .net.
Take idea from these specified links and implement in vb.net..

[How can I open a telnet connection and run a few commands in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053468/how-can-i-open-a-telnet-connection-and-run-a-few-commands-in-c-sharp)
[Telnet connection using .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906475/telnet-connection-using-net)

> You can use a [System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient%28VS.80%29.aspx) object instead of a
>   socket object, which already has the socket parameters configured to
>   use *ProtocolType.Tcp*

1.Create a new TcpClient object, which takes a server name and a port (no IPEndPoint necessary, nice).
2.Pull a NetworkStream out of the TcpClient by calling GetStream()
3.Convert your message into bytes using Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string)
4.Now you can send and receive data using the stream.Write and stream.Read methods, respectively. The stream.Read method returns the number of bytes written to your receiving array, by the way.
5.Put the data back into human-readable format using Encoding.ASCII.GetString(byte array).
6.Clean up your mess before the network admins get mad by calling stream.Close() and client.Close().

Ref:[C# 2.0* and Telnet - Not As Painful As It Sounds](http://geekswithblogs.net/bigpapa/archive/2007/10/08/C-2.0-and-Telnet---Not-As-Painful-As-It.aspx)

```
// Create a TcpClient.
    // Note, for this client to work you need to have a TcpServer 
    // connected to the same address as specified by the server, port
    // combination.
    Int32 port = 13000;
    TcpClient client = new TcpClient(server, port);

    // Translate the passed message into ASCII and store it as a Byte array.
    Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);         

    // Get a client stream for reading and writing.
   //  Stream stream = client.GetStream();

    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

    // Send the message to the connected TcpServer. 
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

    Console.WriteLine("Sent: {0}", message);
```

Comment: I've just tried that, however it fails at: Dim client As TcpClient = New TcpClient(ServerMod, port) as it says the target machine refuses connection.  Even though when I do a telnet it works

Comment: check the target machine firewall refusing the connection for the port.. add the port in firewall exception list..

Answer (score 0):

I made this for a project at work.
I think it's a complete general solution for most people's needs
However, This is my first real .net project so feel free to critique it.

Modeled on http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/63201/TelnetSocket

```
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.IO
Imports System.IO.Pipes

Public Class TelnetClient
  Private Server As String
  Private NetWorkProtocolClient As System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient
  Private ServerStream As System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream
  Private DoReader As Boolean
  Private ReaderThread As Thread
  Private OutputPipe As AnonymousPipeServerStream
  Private WaitForString As String
  Private WaitForStringEvent As New AutoResetEvent(False)

  ReadOnly Property IsConnected() As Boolean
    Get
      Return (Not (IsNothing(NetWorkProtocolClient)) AndAlso (NetWorkProtocolClient.Connected))
    End Get
  End Property

  ReadOnly Property ConnectedTo() As String
    Get
      If (Not (IsNothing(NetWorkProtocolClient)) AndAlso (NetWorkProtocolClient.Connected)) Then
        Return NetWorkProtocolClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString()
      Else
        Return "Nothing"
      End If
    End Get
  End Property

  'Set the Server string to connect to.
  Public Sub SetServer(ByVal new_server As String)
    'double check this later
    Server = new_server
  End Sub
  'Connects if possilbe. If already conneced to some thing it Disconnects from old Telnet and connects to new Telnet.
  Public Sub Connect()
    Try
      If (Not (IsNothing(NetWorkProtocolClient))) AndAlso NetWorkProtocolClient.Connected Then
        Disconnect()
      End If
      If Not IsNothing(Server) Then
        NetWorkProtocolClient = New System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient(Server, 23)
        If NetWorkProtocolClient.Connected Then
          'clear on a new client
          WaitForString = Nothing
          WaitForStringEvent.Reset()

          NetWorkProtocolClient.NoDelay = True
          ServerStream = NetWorkProtocolClient.GetStream()
          ServerStream.ReadTimeout = 1000
          DoReader = True
          ReaderThread = New Thread(AddressOf ReaderTask)
          ReaderThread.IsBackground = True
          ReaderThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.AboveNormal
          ReaderThread.Start()
        End If
      End If
    Catch ex As System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
      Console.WriteLine("SocketException Connect: {0}", ex)
    End Try
  End Sub

  'Disconnects if connected, otherwise does nothing.
  Public Sub Disconnect()
    Try
      If ReaderThread.IsAlive Then
        DoReader = False
        ReaderThread.Join(1000)
      End If
      If (Not (IsNothing(NetWorkProtocolClient))) Then
        ServerStream.Close()
        NetWorkProtocolClient.Close()
      End If
    Catch ex As System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
      Console.WriteLine("SocketException Disconnect: {0}", ex)
    End Try
  End Sub

  'Returns true if found before timeout milliseconds. Use -1 to have infinite wait time.
  'Returns false if timeout occured.
  Public Function WaitFor(ByVal command As String, ByVal timeout As Integer) As Boolean
    WaitForString = New String(command)
    WaitForStringEvent.Reset()
    Dim was_signaled As Boolean = False
    'Block until a the right value from reader or user defined timeout
    was_signaled = WaitForStringEvent.WaitOne(timeout)
    WaitForString = Nothing
    Return was_signaled
  End Function

  Public Sub Write(ByVal command As String)
    Try
      If (Not (IsNothing(NetWorkProtocolClient))) Then
        If NetWorkProtocolClient.Connected Then
          'Write the value to the Stream
          Dim bytes() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(command)
          SyncLock ServerStream
            ServerStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
          End SyncLock
        End If
      End If
    Catch ex As System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
      Console.WriteLine("SocketException Write: {0}", ex)
    End Try
  End Sub

  'appends CrLf for the caller
  Public Sub WriteLine(ByVal command As String)
    Try
      If (Not (IsNothing(NetWorkProtocolClient))) Then
        If NetWorkProtocolClient.Connected Then
          'Write the value to the Stream
          Dim bytes() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(command & vbCrLf)
          SyncLock ServerStream
            ServerStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
          End SyncLock
        End If
      End If
    Catch ex As System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
      Console.WriteLine("SocketException Write: {0}", ex)
    End Try
  End Sub

  'Get a pipe to read output. Note: anything written by WriteLine may be echoed back if the other Telnet offers to do it.
  Public Function GetPipeHandle() As String
    If Not IsNothing(ReaderThread) AndAlso ReaderThread.IsAlive AndAlso Not IsNothing(OutputPipe) Then
      Return OutputPipe.GetClientHandleAsString
    Else
      Return Nothing
    End If
  End Function

  'Task that watches the tcp stream, passes info to the negotiation function and signals the WaitFor task.
  Private Sub ReaderTask()
    Try
      OutputPipe = New AnonymousPipeServerStream(PipeDirection.Out)
      Dim prevData As New String("")
      While (DoReader)
        If (Not (IsNothing(NetWorkProtocolClient))) Then

          If ServerStream.DataAvailable Then

            'Grab Data
            Dim data As [Byte]() = New [Byte](NetWorkProtocolClient.ReceiveBufferSize) {}
            Dim bytes As Integer = ServerStream.Read(data, 0, data.Length)

            'Negotiate anything that came in
            bytes = Negotiate(data, bytes)

            If (bytes > 0) Then
              'append previous to the search sting incase messages were fragmented
              Dim s As New String(prevData & System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetChars(data))

              'If Pipe is connected send it remaining real data
              If OutputPipe.IsConnected Then
                OutputPipe.Write(data, 0, bytes)
              End If

              'Check remaining against WaitForString
              If Not IsNothing(WaitForString) Then
                If s.Contains(WaitForString) Then
                  WaitForStringEvent.Set()
                  'clear prevData buffer because the WaitForString was found
                  prevData = New String("")
                Else
                  'Nothing found make the current string part of the next string.
                  prevData = New String(s)
                End If
              Else
                prevData = New String("")
              End If
            End If

          Else
            Thread.Sleep(100)
          End If
        End If
      End While
      OutputPipe.Close()
      OutputPipe.Dispose()
    Catch ex As System.IO.IOException
      Console.WriteLine("IO Error: {0}", ex)
    Catch ex As System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
      Console.WriteLine("SocketException Reader: {0}", ex)
    End Try
  End Sub

  'Shamelessly adapted from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/63201/TelnetSocket
  'The basic algorithm used here is:
  ' Iterate across the incoming bytes
  ' Assume that an IAC (byte 255) is the first of a two- or three-byte Telnet command and handle it:
  '   If two IACs are together, they represent one data byte 255
  '   Ignore the Go-Ahead command
  '   Respond WONT to all DOs and DONTs
  '   Respond DONT to all WONTs
  '   Respond DO to WILL ECHO and WILL SUPPRESS GO-AHEAD
  '   Respond DONT to all other WILLs
  ' Any other bytes are data; ignore nulls, and shift the rest as necessary
  ' Return the number of bytes that remain after removing the Telnet command and ignoring nulls
  Private Function Negotiate(ByVal data As Byte(), ByVal length As Int32) As Int32
    Dim index As Int32 = 0
    Dim remaining As Int32 = 0

    While (index < length)
      If (data(index) = TelnetBytes.IAC) Then
        Try
          Select Case data(index + 1)
            Case TelnetBytes.IAC
              data(remaining) = data(index)
              remaining += 1
              index += 2

            Case TelnetBytes.GA
              index += 2

            Case TelnetBytes.WDO
              data(index + 1) = TelnetBytes.WONT
              SyncLock ServerStream
                ServerStream.Write(data, index, 3)
              End SyncLock
              index += 3

            Case TelnetBytes.DONT
              data(index + 1) = TelnetBytes.WONT
              SyncLock ServerStream
                ServerStream.Write(data, index, 3)
              End SyncLock
              index += 3

            Case TelnetBytes.WONT
              data(index + 1) = TelnetBytes.DONT
              SyncLock ServerStream
                ServerStream.Write(data, index, 3)
              End SyncLock
              index += 3

            Case TelnetBytes.WILL
              Dim action As Byte = TelnetBytes.DONT

              Select Case data(index + 2)

                Case TelnetBytes.ECHO
                  action = TelnetBytes.WDO

                Case TelnetBytes.SUPP
                  action = TelnetBytes.WDO

              End Select
              data(index + 1) = action
              SyncLock ServerStream
                ServerStream.Write(data, index, 3)
              End SyncLock
              index += 3

          End Select

        Catch ex As System.IndexOutOfRangeException
          index = length
        End Try
      Else
        If (data(index) <> 0) Then
          data(remaining) = data(index)
          remaining += 1
        End If
        index += 1
      End If
    End While

    Return remaining
  End Function

  Private Structure TelnetBytes

    'Commands
    Public Const GA As Byte = 249
    Public Const WILL As Byte = 251
    Public Const WONT As Byte = 252
    Public Const WDO As Byte = 253 'Actually just DO but is protected word in vb.net 
    Public Const DONT As Byte = 254
    Public Const IAC As Byte = 255

    'Options
    Public Const ECHO As Byte = 1
    Public Const SUPP As Byte = 3
  End Structure
End Class
```

Comment: Edited to state my intent that this should work for most, but is not written by a 'pro' by any means.